# Just letting the user book ONE training hour per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I created an application where an user can book a hour of training. The application is already done, but theres an error where an user can book in multiple training hours at the same time.

I would like to do that if the user is already booked, the book button disappear in other trainings (if he gets in the training that he is already booked the unbook button will appear). I would like to ask for help to get this done. My code is the following:

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trainings, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings


  def not_booked?(training)
    bookings.where(training: training).none?
  end
```

Show training view:

```
<div class="row">
   <section>
     <h1>
       HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
     </h1>
   </section>
   <section>
     <h1>
       SLOTS: <%= @training.left_slots %>
     </h1>
   </section>

   <center>
     <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
     <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
   </center>
```

booking_form view:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %>
    <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training),
        class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Unbook",
        training_booking_path(@training, @training.bookings.where(user: current_user).first),
        method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'Sure?' },
        class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For the record, the bookings are deleted everyday at midnight, so all i need is the right code to make the user just book once (if he is booked dont let him book in another hour)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a user has booked a training in your views like so:

```
if current_user.trainings.any? # user booked any training hours?
  if current_user.trainings.include?(@training)
   # user already booked this training hour
   <%= link_to "Unbook",
      training_booking_path(@training, @training.bookings.where(user: 
      current_user).first),
      method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'Sure?' },
      class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  end 
else
  # user hasn't booked any training hours 
  <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training, @booking,
    class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
end
```

First, you check if the user has any training hours; if he has, you check if he already booked the current training and display the **unbook** button but if he hasn't, you display the **book** button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Cesar yes, in place of:

   `<% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %>`

Comment: it gives me the following error when i put if current_user.trainings.any?: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookings", :id=>nil, :training_id=>"6"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: I think that's because `new_training_booking_path` needs both the training and the booking to be passed and you're only passing the training

Comment: Okay i dont get it very well so imma explain what i think i understood.. Instead of using <% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %> i have to do current_user.trainings.any?, and to this method i need to pass the booking like this current_user.trainings.any?(@booking)?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what you need to do exactly. Hope it helps!

Comment: the second if is going to be inside the first if right?

Comment: Yes, nested if.

Comment: Always happy to help!